# Can I have a 'workation' in the USA for two weeks while working for EU company? I already have valid tourist visa

Tags: usa, europe, work

My company allows this and my manager has approved it, however I am waiting for a final approval based on the risk associated with this. I do have a valid tourist visa and would only stay in the US for two weeks. I am looking for any info anyone has regarding the US labor law when it comes to cases such as this. Again, I still waiting for a final approval but looking to familiarize myself with the law before I get the answer. Thank you!